# injectivity of a function.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

We have the map

$\psi$ : {0,1}$^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ ; a= {$a_n$}$_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{10^n}$

I want to show that it is an injection.

The definition of an injection is if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$.

suppose we have $a_n$ and $b_n$ , we want to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{10^n}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{10^n}$ implies that $a_n$ = $b_n$.

surely this cant be injective, we can have two different sequences that both sum to the same thing right? Im pretty sure that im missing the point completely!

I then have to use this to show that the the real line is uncountable but I dont even know where to start to be honest!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which two different sequences sum to the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood your $\psi$ with the function $\phi:\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$ defined by 
$$
\phi((a_1,a_2,a_3,...))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{2^n}
$$, which is indeed **not** an injection. The obvious counterexample is 
$$
\frac 12=\phi((1,0,0,0,...))=\phi((0,1,1,1,...))
$$
However, it can be shown (with a little effort) that $\psi$ as defined is an injection (but not a surjection, however). To show that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, we observe that $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, an uncountable set, is equipotent to a (proper) subset of $\Bbb R$ by the above injection. The [Cantor–Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) theorem can be used to finished the job, i.e. conclude that $\Bbb R$ is indeed uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

For injectivity, suppose that $a \neq b$ but $f(a) = f(b)$. Let $N$ be the first digit such that $a_N = 1 \neq 0=b_N$. Since the sum must equal we must have $$ \frac{1}{10^N} \leq \sum_{n \geq N+1} \frac{1}{10^n}.$$ Is this possible?